# Send Push Notification on All token in database MySql

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification

I've create a push notification for my app, it work perfect but not sending the notification on all devices token.

first I have a database name "member" and it contains id, username, password, token

then I create this php function to send notification

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' );
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
$checktoken = "SELECT token FROM member";
$results = $con->query($checktoken);

if ($results ->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

$regid = array($row["token"]);
echo "" .$row["token"]. " ";
}
}else{
echo "No result";
}

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 'mySound',
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $regid,
    'notification'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

the code only send to one device only, and when I tried to access it in browser it show

> eY0-0uIUDsA:APA91bGmFatL_gtizFRbC9mMbagzsMalJuJ6e_O2poytaKgBTVIsyl5ogJ4-x7PlQebyu6z7ME970H9hdlZUEiLESTNPrSvcn_1PzmKh3AJiwIUZj86_fRxPt9yOpL4k3PZb7Ir6xf43
>   dPEPzRFjnIo:APA91bHBaHO8nZK2g4xF6vzvKrevNhpBRSdIb3NyWrr2PRCEyDR9cLkCZOZ28_hu5pDzdaSKkRxPY1mvYO8ZOnjEscjdKGCEv-FIdIBzrz32mof0rQSlog028kDhv7jltGjWwK7r7l-J
>   {"multicast_id":9198379759567809790,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1513945312938936%cd487dfdcd487dfd"}]}

it has 2 devices there, but why it only send to one device token? any fix for my code?

for your information
first device start with eY0-0uIUDsA:
second one start with dPEPzRFjnIo:

Comment: You overwrite `$regid` on every loop, so in the end only one device will be in there.

Comment: I think you meant to do `$regid[] = $row["token"];` instead of `$regid = array($row["token"]);`. And don't forget to initialize the variable with `$regid = []` before your while loop.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the content of $regid at each loop iteration.
Define the array outside the loop:

```
$regid = [];

if ($results ->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        $regid[] = $row["token"];
        echo "" .$row["token"]. " ";
     }
 } else {
     echo "No result";
 }
```

in addition, better to bring the code which send the notification inside the positive branch of the if, you have to send it only if you got results.